# Detecting Client Disconnects in Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, webservice-client

I'm using the [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) Web Services stack. When a client times out or disconnects from the server before the operation is complete, the server keeps running the operation until it is complete. I would like to have the server detect when the client disconnects and handle that accordingly.

Is there a way to detect when a client disconnects using Apache CXF? What about using other Java web-services stacks?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with **Apache CXF**, but the following should be applicable to any Java Servlet based framework.

In order to determine if a user has disconnected (stop button, closed browser, etc.) the server must attempt to send a packet.  If the TCP/IP connection has been closed, an `IOException` will be thrown.

In theory, a Java application could send a space character at various points during processing.  An `IOException` would signal that the client has gone away and processing can be aborted.

However, there may be a few issues with this technique:

1. Sending characters during processing will cause the response to be "committed", so it may be impossible to set HTTP headers, cookies, etc. based on the result of the long-running serverside processing.
2. If the output stream is buffered, the space characters will not be sent immediately, thereby not performing an adequate test.  It may be possible to use `flush()` as a workaround.
3. It may be difficult to implement this technique for a given framework or view technology (JSP, etc.)  For example, the page rendering code will not be able to sent the content type after the response has been committed.